# indexOf with 2 parameters

Tags: javascript

I currently have this code that returns me the index where it matches on personid.  It works just fine.

However I need to expand it some.  My object also includes `jobid`.  I need this to look for `personid` and `jobid`.  Is there a way to do this with `indexOf` or do I need to loop through my object to find the correct element?

```
pos = eventObjs.map(function (e) { return e.familymemberpersonid; }).indexOf($(element).attr('familymemberpersonid'));
```

Lets say I have an object with 2 properties:
personId and jobId

```
[0]
personId: 1, jobId: 1
[1]
personId: 2, jobId: 1
[2]
personId: 1, jobId: 2
[3]
personId: 2, jobId: 2
```

I want to return index [1] if I know it is personId: 2 AND jobId: 1

Comment: What do you want returned? Javscript can only return a single value, so if you want two, you need to return an array or other object.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to match two object properties of an array element using `indexOf` which is not possible. @webdad3, if you are already willing to loop through the entire array with `map`, why not use `filter` or `reduce` on the array to either retrieve the item you want or to get the index value (not optimal either way)?

Comment: So are these objects in an array? e.g. `[{personId:1, jobId:1},{personId:2, jobId:1},...]`?

Comment: @RobG - yes that is correct

Comment: Depending on the characters in personId and jobId, you might be able to concatenate them to match on a single string, so `return e.familymemberpersonid + ':' + e.familymemberperjobid` in the *map* function to create an array of `personid:jobid`, then  `indexOf($(element).attr('familymemberpersonid') + ':' + $(element).attr('familymemberjobid'))` (though it would be best to cache `$(element)` or use *getAttribute* instead).

Comment: @RobG, using `map` to find an index is inefficient as it will loop through the entire array no matter where the item is (if a match exists). Using one of the polyfills mentioned in my answer will exit the loop as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: @JasonCust—sure, ES5 *some* can do the same.

Comment: @RobG `some` will only return `true` or `false` and not an index or item. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider concatenating the two values so you only have one string to search for, e.g.:

```
var pos = eventObjs.map(function (e) {
            return e.familymemberpersonid + ':' + e.familymemberjobid;
          }).indexOf(element.getAttribute('familymemberpersonid') + ':' +
                     element.getAttribute('familymemberjobid'));
```

You should be able to use ES5's Array.prototype.some, which will return as soon as a match is found.

```
var pos = (function() {

            // To store current position outside callback
            var pos;

            // Store element attribute values
            var pID = element.getAttribute('familymemberpersonid');
            var jID = element.getAttribute('familymemberjobid');

            // Returns true when first match is found
            var found = eventObjs.some(function (e, i) {
              pos = i;
              return e.familymemberpersonid == pID && e.familymemberjobid == jID;
           };

           // If match found, return position. Otherwise, return null (or whatever value suits)
           return found? pos : null;
         }());
```

Comment: This is an inefficient method as you are looping through the array once completely with `map` and then looping through the same array to find a match with `indexOf`.

Comment: `some` will only return `true` or `false` and not an index or item. :)

Comment: Yes, but if you remember the index where it returned true, and only return that if it did return true… ;-)

Comment: Seems like a long walk to get to the same place :)

Comment: But does not need a polyfill. If it was my problem, I'd probably write a function to do the job with a simple loop. It would be faster and easier to maintain, each to their own.

Comment: @RobG - That is exactly what I did.  I wrote a simple loop.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: If the current tools fit the job then I would agree but this is verging on using a screwdriver for a hammer. The polyfill approach future proofs the code base (which reduces maintenance) as well as making it explicitly clear to a future maintainer (including the OP) what the intention of the code is. It's a clever solution but there is a balance between being clever and readability/comprehension: one line of code that clearly states what it does versus a clever function that approximates the same functionality but requires multiple comments to explain what it's for. To each his own. :)

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the documentation for [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf): "*indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).*" So you won't be able to match an array item's object property using it. What you need is [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). However both are only available in ECMA6 so you would need to use one of the polyfills noted in the documentation.

Example using `findIndex`:

```
pos = eventObjs.findIndex(function (e) { return e.personId === 2 && e.jobId === 1; });
```

Comment: This seems like a more appropriate answer,  but it is only supported by FF right now.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's what the polyfill is for. It's a simply copy/paste from the documentation and future proofs your code.